# database structure for storing daily rent

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

My current database structure

```
cars(id,name,created)

rents(id,car_id,date,rent)
```

Car rent is changing every day

So I put 366 rows in rents table for each car

Is There any better database structure for storing daily rent

Comment: You could use date_ini, date_end and do some rentals with intervals if possible

Comment: If is put range Jan 1st to Jan 31st and then change rent for Jan 15th how to do that

Comment: table rents: Jan 1st to Jan 14th,100€.  and  Jan 15th to Jan 31th 200€ (or Sept 2nd, whenever it changes again). As I said, if possible

Comment: so with that db structure what is the query to get rent on Jan 5th

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing a research i found following solution

In this scenario I insert rent by intervals and If I want to modify rent for a particular date I insert that one too

While getting rent for a particular date I choose the latest 1

Database

```
cars(id,name,created)
101,Rolls-Royce,2014-02-12 09:33:31
102,Rolls-Royce,2014-02-12 09:33:31

rents(id,car_id,start_date,end_date,rent,created)
11,101,2014-03-01,2014-03-31,2000,2014-02-12 10:33:31
12,101,2014-03-10,2014-03-10,2000,2014-02-12 11:35:36
```

Query

```
$id = 101
$date = 2014-03-10
SELECT rent FROM rents WHERE car_id='$id' and '$date' between start_date and end_date ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 1
```